# Load Test Application calling external http service

Tags: load-testing, gatling

Thanks for looking this question, I have an application which reads from JMS Queue and processes the mesages and POST the processed message to external http service. What will be best way to load test using gatling.

I can simulate load on queue using gatling.jms. How to verify POST to external service.

Answer (score 0):

Load testing with Gatling is a fairly complex affair to do it right. I've done it enough to know some of the pitfalls so here is some insight that may be useful:

1. you want to test over the network and you want the latency to be minimal so that delays due to network latency are minimized/nullified and so that the results show how quickly incoming HTTP requests can be handled/responded to. For this reason, if your application is in the cloud in europe-east, say, you want to run your tests from the same location. If your requests were coming from us-west, there'd be a big delay in routing the requests from the wrong side of the US which could introduce big variations in the response times to/from your application.
2. Remove all other load from your service. If you can't remove load because you're hoping to test against a live application, then you need to make another deployment to test against that has no active load
3. Load tests should run for (in my experience) 45 minutes as a minimum to verify your service can handle the load. Reason for this being that it can take time for an unbearable load to accumulate on the server... so you may run at 33req/s which is fine for 40 minutes, but when run for 45-60 mins, its just long enough that the balance between what your application can cope with, vs. what causes catastrophic failure is tipped towards failure.

Notes:

1. You don't need to test to destruction but it is sometimes a useful metric to be aware of. I find using a binary search strategy works well here to get peak load relatively quickly.
2. What you should test is that your application can handle the load you expect it to receive in a worst case scenario; Different organisations have different tolerances for how much load they expect their applications to be able to cope with. At some places I've worked they've used a lot of optimisations to minimise load directly to their servers, but if those protections fail, the server is expected to handle 10x more traffic than the usual load. At other places, those same optimisations were not in place, instead there were be disaster recovery systems available, ready to pick up when the main app fails. In this case the application only needed to be able to handle 2x the peak load (as observed by assessing logs/metrics for the past year).
3. I work predominantly with garbage collected languages on the JVM. I'm aware there are now Zero Garbage Collection designs/capabilities which could help minimize the effects of a buildup of GC tasks... so there are almost always optimisations you can make either with language/memory settings, database indexing, or within your application itself, or the strategies you employ to perform a task effectively, before you start changing the hardware.
4. Peak load can be assessed from logs/metrics systems